# Wifi won't connect even though it shows all the ssid

Tags: debian, wifi, usb

Debian 9 - installed 2 days ago.
Installed firmware-misc-nonfree_20161130-3_all.deb.
Os is recognizing wifi adapter and network manager is showing all the available connections.
No matter what I try, it won't connect.
Any tips or solutions ?
Thanks

Comment: Try disabling `bluetooth`. If still it doesn't work than try live booting some other distro and check if WiFi is working. You can try Antergos, Fedora

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Wifi works, i have been using that device for quite some time now.

Comment: The problem is with the WiFi driver. Can you tell on which OS was WiFi working earlier?

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal works with Windows 7 8 and 10

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal haven't tried it with Linux, but if it's the problem with the driver, how come the network manager of Debian is able to show all the ssid that are being broadcasted

Comment: I will highly recommend you to try some other distro other than debian based. Debian is likely to have these kinds of problems. One of my friend has HP laptop and he isn't able to connect to WiFi though it detects SSID.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal i see, thanks for the i/p

Comment: Run `killall wapsupplicant` , `wpa_supplicant -B -i your-interface -c <(wpa_passphrase your-SSID your-pass)` then `dhclient your-interface` .

Comment: Thanks for the i/p guys ! I left Debian and I am on pure Arch now, its awesome and I dont see myself going back to Debian

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, that could be fixed by

```
 $ apt install gnome-keyring
```

Actually I could connect to any previously saved networks, but when trying to connect to something else, `nm-applet` would not be able to popup the password input box, hence silently prevented me to connect to the network.

Similar report: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185742.